# trying to make a responsive div

Tags: html, css

I am not able to make a responsive text 'W E L C O M E'. I tried media queries but I failed to. There is my HTML and CSS code in a snippet, tried to run it here but have some problems too.

As u can see there is a text with some animation, it must to be done this way, with single letters as 'li'

```css
#bg1 {
    background: url(img/38890540-cosmic-pictures-wallpapers.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#bg2 {
    background-color: darkgray;
}

#bg3 {
    background-color: darkgreen;
}

#bg4 {
    background-color: darkslateblue;
}

.fly-in-text {
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.fly-in-text li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 50px;
    font-family: Quicksand, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 4em;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 2.5s ease;
}

.fly-in-text li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.fly-in-text.hidden li {
    opacity: 0;
}

.fly-in-text.hidden li:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translateX(-200px) translateY(-200px);
}

.fly-in-text.hidden li:nth-child(2) {
    transform: translateX(20px) translateY(100px);
}

.fly-in-text.hidden li:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translateX(-150px) translateY(-80px);
}

.fly-in-text.hidden li:nth-child(4) {
    transform: translateX(10px) translateY(-200px);
}

.fly-in-text.hidden li:nth-child(5) {
    transform: translateX(-300px) translateY(200px);
}

.fly-in-text.hidden li:nth-child(6) {
    transform: translateX(20px) translateY(-20px);
}

.fly-in-text.hidden li:nth-child(7) {
    transform: translateX(30px) translateY(200px);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.fullPage.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    <title>x</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="fullpage">
        <div class="section" id="bg1">
            <ul class="fly-in-text hidden">
                <li>W</li>
                <li>E</li>
                <li>L</li>
                <li>C</li>
                <li>O</li>
                <li>M</li>
                <li>E</li>
            </ul>

        </div>

        <div class="section" id="bg2"></div>
        <div class="section" id="bg3"></div>
        <div class="section" id="bg4"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="section">
        <div class="slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="slide">Slide 3</div>
        <div class="slide">Slide 4</div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage();
        });

        $(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('.fly-in-text').removeClass('hidden');
            }, 500);
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: by responsive text you mean what? font size should increase/decrease  depending on resolution?

Comment: yeah, it should be always in one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `font-size` with `vw`

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/91fmerzf/

When you resize frame you can see that after animation it always ends in one line.